# How do you survive the plague?

Tags: guild-2

In The Guild 2, how on earth do I survive the plague?
As soon as it hits town, All my family members seem to get it. Before I know it, my entire dynasty has been wiped out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stay in the house, put all ill members in a seperated one. Let the ill people sleep and hope that they will survive. That's the only possibility - but yeah, plague and pest are a pain in the ass.

Comment: Consulting a doctor can also help but is by no means a guarantee (plague and all that..)

Comment: If the Hospital has resources it's possible to get away with it, but like I said, HOSPITAL. I believe it has to be maxed.